# How to make a listbox or a drop-down-menu plugin for adobe premiere?

Tags: c++, plugins, adobe, after-effects, adobe-premiere

Re-read the documentation for adobe premiere but did not find how to do it.

Plugin (video effect it) or video filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use example "Upvisor" with Adobe After Efects SDK. It works in adobe-premiere